# Pricerule showing in store but not checkout

Tags: magento-1.9

Have a peculiar problem and could do with some insight on where to begin;

In the store I have a custom pricerule for customers, now whats weird is in the store lets say we have a product:

Product 1
Price: 100

Now in the store my customer has a 20% discount so it says it cost 80, but when they add it to the cart at checkout it says it costs 100 and when proceeding with checkout it stays at 100.

Where would I start with fixing this?

[image: fig 1]
[image: fig 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

An attribute wasn't correctly imported, when I added unassigned attribute (discount code) it worked fine, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The start is probably to check the rule by itself and to which public it applies.

- Is the catalog rule compatible with all shopping cart rule ?
- Is the group of the customer who runs the checkout eligible to that rule ?

You can then check if no module alters the consistence of the rules. I had problem with shopping cart rules on login but not with catalog's.

Comment: Sorry to sound noob but how to I go about doing those things and think my problem is the same as yours was `I had problem with shopping cart rules on login but not with catalog's.`

Comment: attached images

Comment: did you check that the customer is eligible to this rule in backoffice ? if yes, the problem is a bit deeper, I solved it by updating from 1.7 to 1.9.